# Is it possible to use IWindowManager from Micro.Caliburn in Prism UnityContainer

Tags: c#, mvvm, unity-container, caliburn.micro

I was looking a WindowManager for UnityContainer and I register in my container this service.

But at the momento when I plan to utilize this service to show a UserControl, it's not possible. It tells that it can't find a view for the view model 'x'.

I'm using Unity as the bootstrapper.

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        MainWindow shell = Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        shell.Show();

        return shell;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        Container.RegisterInstance<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you customised the conventions? Is your view named MainWindowView? Have you had much experience with CM? It might be worth reading up on the default conventions if you aren't

Comment: Basically the fact that it can't find a view just means the conventions used to find the view aren't matching the views typename, most likely due to where you've put the view vs viewmodel and the fact that you may not have customised the convention manager to suit your convention

Comment: Info for conventions is here: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Configuration%2c%20Actions%20and%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation the default implementation just replaces ViewModel with View (as far as I can remember) on namespaces and on typenames.